# Explanation for in loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Who can explain  how this for in loop works and why it's assign keys of object to array

```js
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
var a = [],
  i = 0;
for (a[i++] in o);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Its like `for each` in other languages. Its traverse through each object in collection.

Comment: Any Javascript tutorial should explain how `for-in` works.

Comment: @Barmar there is one more trick hidden in this :)

Comment: The for/in statement only loops through the properties of an object.
The block of code inside the loop will be executed once for each property. It is bad idea to use it since it is not good for performance comparitively with other javascript looping approches.

Comment: @Khaleel there is no block of code here, and what are better looping approaches for objects?

Comment: `it is not good for performance comparitively` - if there where thousands of keys in the object that may be a consideration

Comment: @mplungjan to make sure the variables used in the loop are declared in the function containing the loop like `for (var property in object)`  which is faster than the `for (property in object)` in the question. also refer precompiled iterator approach http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-with-pre-compiled-iterator

Comment: @Hemal It does not "traverse through each object in collection"; it traverses through **each property in object**.

Comment: @Khaleel What other looping approach do you suggest? How would you loop through the properties of an object without looping through them? I would definitely not recommend some complex unrolling strategy. That would almost necessary be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using a side effect when [enumerating the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), and using [an empty statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty), each key is stored in the array a; first key in a[0], next in a[1] etc.

It is not necessary however since you could just use `Object.keys(o)`

```js
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
var a = [],
  i = 0;
for (a[i++] in o); // do nothing loop
console.log(a,Object.keys(o));
```